# User input for getters and setters

Tags: java, oop, getter-setter

So basically what I'm trying to do is get the user to input the variables through the `car.setxxxx(scan.nextLine());`line, however there is an error : *TestVehicle.java:21: error: method setModel in class Vehicle cannot be applied to given types;
car.setModel(scan.nextLine());*
^
*required: no arguments
found:    String
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length*
Any idea why this is happening?

Main method:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TestVehicle{

    public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        Vehicle car = new Vehicle();


    System.out.print("Input name: ");   
    car.setName(scan.nextLine());
    System.out.print("Input model: ");
    car.setModel(scan.nextLine());
```

Vehicle Class:

```
public class Vehicle {
    private String name;
    private String model;

public Vehicle(){

}   

public Vehicle(String name, String model){
this.name = name;
this.model = model;
public String getName(){
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
}   
public String getModel(){
    return model;
}   
public void setModel(){
    this.model = model;
```

Comment: You are properly missing a parameter here `setModel()`.

Answer (score 0):

I can see from setting the model that you haven't added any parameters.

```
public void setModel(String modelName) {
this.model = modelName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the `setModel` method, it doesn't accept any parameter.

Correct it to

```
public void setModel(String model){
    this.model = model;
}
```